# why is the google location api is less accurate that the google maps on the phone?

Tags: android, google-maps

the question is itching my mind .why is the google maps android app accuracy is not the same as the accuracy that you get when you develop an app that uses there API

Answer (score 0):

One thing it is dependent on the kind of permission you are asking the user in the manifest.

ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION:- approximate location.
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION:- Precise location as possible.

Also, check the below answer:-
[Android - get coordinates accurately like Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68899155/android-get-coordinates-accurately-like-google-maps)